# ARMA model not the same as training and testing graph

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am doing a time series forecasting to predict future classes, but the problem is for ARMA it seems like the axises are not the same as the training and testing model

input data:

```
| date | class_id |count |
|-|-|-|
|2021-09-01|A|13|
|2021-09-01 | B | 2|
|2021-09-02 | A | 1|
|2021-09-02 | C | 7|
|2021-09-04 | A | 5|
```

```
from google.colab import drive
drive.mount('/content/gdrive', force_remount = True)

import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('gdrive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/classproject/classdata.csv')
new = visit_date1.str.split(" ", n=1, expand=True)
visit_date2= new[0]
visit_date3= pd.to_datetime(visit_date2)

data2= data.drop(['visit_date'],axis=1)
data2.insert(3,"visit_date",visit_date3,True)


# count the number of patients within the day by doctor
class_id = data['class_id']
m1 = class_id.ne(class_id.shift())
m2 = visit_date.ne(visit_date.shift())
data2['visit_count'] = data2.groupby((m1 | m2).cumsum()).cumcount().add(1).values

data3 =data2.groupby(data2['visit_date'],as_index=False).sum('count') #,as_index=False
Visdate = data3.visit_date

data3=data3.set_index('visit_date')

import pandas_datareader.data as web
import datetime

import pandas as pd
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set()

plt.ylabel('Classes')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)

Vdate = data3.index
VCount= data3.visit_count
plt.plot(Vdate, VCount, )
```

[image]

this is where I combined the graphs together but for some reason the x axis for ARMA is off from the test and training data

```
train = data3[Vdate < pd.to_datetime("2022-11-01", format='%Y-%m-%d')]
test = data3[Vdate > pd.to_datetime("2022-11-01", format='%Y-%m-%d')]
y = train['visit_count']
#x = train['visit_date']

ARMAmodel = SARIMAX(y, order = (1, 0, 1))
ARMAmodel = ARMAmodel.fit()

y_pred = ARMAmodel.get_forecast(len(test.index))
y_pred_df = y_pred.conf_int(alpha = 0.05)
y_pred_df["Predictions"] = ARMAmodel.predict(start = y_pred_df.index[0], end = y_pred_df.index[-1])
y_pred_df.index = test.index
y_pred_out = y_pred_df["Predictions"]

plt.plot(y_pred_out, test['visit_count'], color='green', label = 'Predictions')
plt.plot(train, color='black')
plt.plot(test, color='red')
plt.ylabel('Number of Class')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.xticks(rotation=45)
plt.title("Train/Test split for Class Data")
plt.show()

plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here you're not providing any X-asis data for the plot, so the index are just from the y data as x-axes.

```
plt.plot(y_pred_out, color='green', label = 'Predictions')
```

I think you can solve it like this:

```
y_date = out['date'][out['date'] < pd.to_datetime("2022-11-01",='%Y-%m-%d')]
plt.plot(y_date, y_pred_out, color='green', label = 'Predictions')
```

Comment: it gives me a key error message, I added it to the question above

Comment: @Sonny yeah makes sence, the y only contains the 'count' ofcourse. So we will need to create some y_date like :

`y_date = out['date'][out['date'] < pd.to_datetime("2022-11-01", format='%Y-%m-%d')]`

After which we can use:

`plt.plot(y_date, y_pred_out, color='green', label = 'Predictions')`

Also modified the awnser

Comment: okay but it only gives me the green graph, im supposed to have the black and red graph behind it too, here is the blog I got most of the code from: https://builtin.com/data-science/time-series-forecasting-python

Comment: @Sonny Ah alright this was not clear for me from your question. But the difference is that your running this in a ipython notebook so the global variables are not transfered from cell to cell (which are creating the plot). If you but all the plotting code into 1 cell you should be fine. Or just use a python script. Hope this helps.

Comment: hi it works but for some reason the green x axis is not proportionate to the train and test data, I put the code changes and results above

Comment: @Sonny Nice, but know you still have to replace this:
`plt.plot(y_pred_out, color='green', label = 'Predictions')`
with the code I provided and you should be fine.

Comment: hi sorry I changed the code a little could you help to take a look thanks